# How do you pipe the output of vboxmanage clonemedium into dd

Tags: hard-drive, virtualbox, virtual-machine, pipe

I want to pipe my converted `.vdi` file into `/dev/sda`. My `box.vdi` is 2TB and my HDD is also 2TB, but the system I am doing the conversion from is only 128GB. All the resources ([ref1](https://superuser.com/questions/114445/is-it-possible-to-convert-virtual-machines-to-physical-environments) and [ref2](https://superuser.com/a/241489/401540)) I can find say I need to write it to an intermediate file and then `dd` that `.img` file into `/dev/sda`.

When I run: `vboxmanage clonemedium box.vdi /dev/null --format=RAW`; I get: `VBoxManage: error: Cannot create destination file "/dev/null": VERR_ALREADY_EXISTS`; Same with trying to write to `/dev/sda`.

[This](https://superuser.com/a/255273/401540) answer suggests I can use a pipe, but I get the error `error: unknown option: -` and that answer if from an old version of VirtualBox.

```
# vboxmanage clonemedium  box.vdi - --format=RAW | dd of=/dev/null

Oracle VM VirtualBox Command Line Management Interface Version 7.0.12
Copyright (C) 2005-2023 Oracle and/or its affiliates

VBoxManage: error: unknown option: -

Usage - Create a clone of a medium:

  VBoxManage clonemedium <uuid | source-medium> <uuid | target-medium> [disk | dvd | floppy] [--existing]
      [--format= VDI | VMDK | VHD | RAW | other ] [--variant=Standard,Fixed,Split2G,Stream,ESX]
```

```
# vboxmanage clonemedium  box.vdi --format=RAW | dd of=/dev/null              
Oracle VM VirtualBox Command Line Management Interface Version 7.0.12
Copyright (C) 2005-2023 Oracle and/or its affiliates

VBoxManage: error: Mandatory output file parameter missing
```

Answer (score 3):

A good enough solution to this involves using `vboxmanage internalcommands createrawvmdk --filename mapped_drive.vdi --rawdisk /dev/sdX` to map a `.vdi` file to the physical drive. Then you can attach the mapped drive and the drive you want to clone on a new vm. Inside the vm both drives will appear and you can use `dd if=/dev/sdb of=/dev/sdc` or `pv /dev/sdb --sync > /dev/sdc` to copy the data from one to the other.